# FileSystemWatcher: how to rise events only for new files in directory?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

FileSystemWatcher: how to rise events only for new files in directory?

I have a directory, which my service scan. And I use `FileSystemWatcher`:

constructor:

```
if(Directory.Exists(_dirPath))
{
    _fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_dirPath);
}
```

Then, I subscribes on Directory:

```
public void Subscribe()
{
    try
    {
        //if (_fileSystemWatcher != null)
        //{
        //    _fileSystemWatcher.Created -= FileSystemWatcher_Created;
        //    _fileSystemWatcher.Dispose();
        //}

        if (Directory.Exists(_dirPath))
        {                    
            _fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            _fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
            _fileSystemWatcher.Filter = "*.txt";                 
        }                    
}
```

But, the problem is that i want to get events when new files create (or copy).
Instead, i get events from all files in this directory already exists.

How to get event only from new files?
Thank you!

Comment: Your code works for me. It only notifies for newly created files. That is what the `Created` event is supposed to do.

Comment: Did answers solve your problem? if yes don't forget to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 8):

By setting `NotifyFilter` to `NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite` you can watch if new files are created.

You also need to check `e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created` in the raised event after any change occurred.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    string filePath = @"d:\watchDir";
    watcher.Path = filePath;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

    watcher.Filter = "*.*";
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileCreated);

    new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
}

private static void OnFileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
        // some code            
}
```

Comment: Naming the `OnCreated` Event as `OnChanged` while there is an event called `Changed` in the `FileSystemWatcher` class is a bit confusing !

Comment: `e.ChangeType` is the key. Good stuff!

Comment: Is the `ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created` check necessary when the event is already linked to `Created`?

Answer (score 2):

From experience I have noticed that the events that get raised when editing a file can wildly differ depending on the application that edits the the file.

Some applications overwrite, others append.

I found that polling every now and then and keeping a list of files that already existed on the previous poll was more reliable than trying to get the events right.

Comment: OP wants to watch creation of new files in a directory. Append and overwrite is related to update of files.

Comment: @RBT - I have noticed that some applications, when they amend a file, they delete the original and then write the same file with new content. To the OS this looks like a new file and that will raise the new file event.

Comment: Ohh. That's very interesting find.